# How do I fix File is not `goimports`-ed with -local?

Tags: go, format, goimports

How do I fix this error?

```
pkg/path/to/file.go:22: File is not `goimports`-ed with -local github.com/some/repositiory (goimports)
        s "github.com/some/repositiory/pkg/somepkg"
```

If I run `goimports -local pkg/path/to/file.go` the program just seems to get stuck and nothing happens.

`s` is the name I use to refer to `somepkg`, e.g. `s.SomeFunc()`.

Answer (score 3):

You have to run

```
goimports -w -local github.com/some/repositiory pkg/path/to/file.go
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the cause / resolution?

Comment: hey @ÉdouardLopez, `-w` is used to write the results to source file instead of sdout. And you have to define what the local path is with `-local`, that's why the previous answer put it this way. The local imports go after the 3rd party packages. The order is: go std packages, 3rd party ones and then your local ones.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to [run `golangci-lint` on your file](https://github.com/golangci/golangci-lint/issues/1462#issuecomment-713840286):

```
golangci-lint run --fix
```

For me, the fix was adding a new line between the import:

```
    sprig "github.com/go-task/slim-sprig"
+
    "github.com/kubeshop/testkube/pkg/api/v1/testkube"
```